# How do I enable ignite-http-rest module when using the .Net NuGet Apache Ignite package?

Tags: c#, ignite

I have a .Net console project referencing the Apache Ignite Nuget package. I'm interested in running the ignite-rest-http module within this same process. I'm using Apache Ignite 2.0.

I'm referring to the Apache Ignite REST Api as described here:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api

I've tried the "Getting Started":

> To enable HTTP connectivity, make sure that ignite-rest-http module is
>   in classpath. With binary distribution this means copying
>   libs\optional\ignite-rest-http to libs\ignite-rest-http.

However, it didn't seem to work. I started my process and went to http://localhost:8080, but there was no response.

Is it appropriate to host the ignite-rest-http module within a .Net process?

If so, is there something else I need to configure in order to host the ignite-rest-http module in a .Net process?

Comment: Have you tried something from rest api? For example curl http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=version. Which http code you get in answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NuGet package includes a limited set of JARs required for core functionality. Optional libs are not included (NuGet.org has 30 MB package size limit).

To enable ignite-rest-http with NuGet:

- Download full binary package from https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi#binaries
- Extract `libs\optional\ignite-rest-http` contents somewhere, say `c:\ignite-rest-http`
- Provide `IgniteConfiguration.JvmClasspath` property with `;`-separated paths to all http JAR files

  ```
  var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
  {
      JvmClasspath = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\ignite-rest-http")
          .Aggregate((x, y) => x + ";" + y)
  };

  Ignition.Start(cfg);

  Console.WriteLine(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=version"));
  ```

There are plans to include these JARs as a separate NuGet package: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3275