# Starting WebAgent on Apache Ignite for Docker

Tags: docker, ignite

I'm attempting to troubleshoot replication between two apache ignite dotnet nodes in docker.

I've enabled http-rest using the instructions here:
[How do I enable ignite-http-rest module when using the .Net NuGet Apache Ignite package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44532780/1483246)

I put the following in my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  zignite1:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}zignite1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: zIgnite1/Dockerfile

  webagent:
    image: apacheignite/web-agent
    depends_on:
      - zignite1

  webconsole:
    image: apacheignite/web-console-standalone
    depends_on:
    - webagent
```

And my docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  zignite1:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44382
    ports:
      - "10001:80"
      - "44383:443"
      - "8090:8080"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro

  webagent:
    environment:
      - DRIVER_FOLDER=./jdbc-drivers
      - NODE_URI=http://zignite1:8080      
      - SERVER_URI=http://webconsole
      - TOKENS=sometoken 

  webconsole:
    ports:
      - "8095:80"
      - "3002:3001"
```

webagent starts then ends abruptly with the following in the logs:

```
[2019-07-24 08:33:46,279][INFO ][EventThread][AgentLauncher] Connection established.,
[2019-07-24 08:33:46,331][ERROR][EventThread][AgentLauncher] You are using an older version of the agent. Please reload agent,
Agent configuration:,
User's security tokens          : ****************abcd,
URI to Ignite node REST server  : http://zignite1:8080,
URI to Ignite Console server    : http://webconsole,
Path to agent property file     : default.properties,
Path to JDBC drivers folder     : ./jdbc-drivers,
Demo mode                       : enabled,
[2019-07-24 08:33:38,413][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher] Connecting to: http://webconsole,
[2019-07-24 08:33:38,456][ERROR][EventThread][AgentLauncher] Failed to establish connection to server (connection refused).,
[2019-07-24 08:33:39,969][ERROR][EventThread][AgentLauncher] Failed to receive response from server (connection refused).,
[2019-07-24 08:33:42,731][ERROR][EventThread][AgentLauncher] Failed to receive response from server (connection refused).
```

I've pulled the latest images from apacheignite/web-agent so:
1. Where can I get the latest ignite web-agent binaries?
2. How do I add it to the existing image so that it works?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you should rebuild docker image by using next steps:

1. Start Web Console, log in and download Web Agent by using link in the right bottom side.
2. Copy downloaded Web Agent archive and Dockerfile (can be found here https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/docker/web-agent) to the same folder
3. Build the image by using steps 3-5 from README file

NOTICE: seems like current version of Dockerfile contains bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12018, according to the suggestion from the ticket you should change COPY command in Dockerfile to `COPY ignite-web-agent* ./`

Comment: I'm getting a similar(ish) error: as well as the one above:  "/bin/sh: ./ignite-web-agent.sh: not found."  I wonder if it's related.

Comment: Seems like no files were copied inside image at all. Please double-check that downloaded archive has name in the format "ignite-web-agent-*.zip" and you've unpacked it to the folder near the Dockerfile. Also are you sure that you're using Dockerfile from GitHub with updated line for COPY command?