# apacheignite/web-agent:2.7.0 /2.6.0 both the images looks like corrupted

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

`apacheignite/web-agent:2.7.0 / 2.6.0` both the images looks like corrupted. Giving an error `Failed to find agent property file: default.properties` & `You are using an older version of the agent. Please reload agent`

Is there any working Image available?

Answer (score 0):

1. `You are using an older version of the agent. Please reload agent` - this message comes because you're trying to use a web-agent whose version is less than your web-console's version (I suppose it could be 2.6.0 WA with 2.7.0 WC). They should correspond to each other.
2. `Failed to find agent property file: default.properties` - you need a `default.properties` file to be able to connect to a specific web-console, it should be based on connection details like url(s), token etc. You can try to build your own image to get rid of this error. Steps can be found in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57210654/5558122)